# Unmounting the partition currently in use

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

OK, here's my scenario: I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10, and I want to shrink my windows 10 partition, and allocate the free space to my Ubuntu partition. I have shrunk my Windows partition using GParted, now I need to extend my Ubuntu partition. Now, to do this, I figured I'd just go onto Windows 10 and extend my Ubuntu partition. Unfortunately, Windows 10 disk partitioning is super confusing and fiddly, so I'm trying to use Gparted instead. To extend my Ubuntu partition, I've been told I first need to unmount it, but I'm unsure whether to do this or not, as I don't want to unmount a partition that I'm in the middle of using.

tl;dr: Will unmounting the partition I'm currently using break my computer?

Sorry for the wall of text, and thanks for reading.

EDIT: I have tried using GParted live CD however I get tmp (7) errors, buffer I/O error and a few more. It will not boot in failsafe mode or safe mode.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this would be to boot from a live USB, and use "gparted" from there.  Often, you can extend a partition in use, but it's not always possible depending upon what is being done to the partitions.

Comment: Shrinking your windows partition using gparted may be a bad idea. I broke a windows system this way, as others have.  Best to operate on windows partitions using windows tools.